# Unintentional Beamforming

Tags: wireless, digital-communications

Suppose I have two cross polarized transmit antennas sending the same signal in a rather line-of-sight dominated  environment to a receive antenna, is there any chance of creating unintentional beamforming or would this be rather highly unlikely?

Comment: Are the antennas sending the same signal?

Comment: And when you say two cross polarized antennas, do you mean the two antennas are orthogonal, e-field wise,  to one another?  That is, if one is x-pol, is the other y-pol?

Comment: If the polarization states are completely orthogonal then they don't interfere and it's like each one is alone, at least as long as there's no depolarization from scattering, etc.

Comment: Yes it is the same signal and yes the two antennas are orthogonal .That is, if one is x-pol,  the other y-pol. What are the chances that scattering could cause coherent combining of the two signals somewhere at the receive antenna in the far field? Slim?

Comment: First, the two polarization states, even in well designed antenna elements, are never perfectly isolated.  20 dB isolation would be very sporty, and 15 dB isolation is more practical. So there will be some cross-pol interference between the two antennas.  How much you can tolerate depends on your application.

Comment: As was mentioned, scattering/reflections can cause an EM wave to flip polarizations.  Sometimes this is advantage, as in some radar system which might transmit on one pol and receive on the other.  How much of a problem this causes for you depends on your environment and where the scatterers or reflectors are located.

Answer (score 1):

If you send the same signal on horizontal polarization as on vertical polarization, you end up with a slant polarized signal at +45 deg, and nothing at -45 deg (or vice versa).

If you can CHOOSE whether you send it on either of two orthogonal polarizations, making the choice which gives the best signal at the receiver, then in many situations these two channels fade relatively independently and you get some diversity gain. Cellular operators used to do something similar in urban environments, using polarization diversity for the base station reception.  You have two colocated antennas with different polarizations  and you can choose the better signal (or even better optimally combine the two).  It works better in cluttered environments where you get polarization mixing on scattering, it doesn't work so well in open fields.

Comment: "If you send the same signal on horizontal polarization as on vertical polarization, you end up with a slant polarized signal at +45 deg, and nothing at -45 deg (or vice versa)."  I don't think it works that way.  It what you described, you will have two orthogonally polarized EM waves, not a single slant polarized wave.

Comment: Think of what happens with a rotating dipole in the far field.  At one of the 45 deg the two signals add and at the other they cancel, so you have slant polarization.

Comment: I'm going to have to think about that.  But, at 0 deg the dipole just receives the 0 deg pol signal, and at 90 deg it would just receive the 90 deg pol signal, within the limits of how well the dipole rejects the cross pol.

Comment: And the signals aren't going to add at one 45 deg position and cancel at the other 45 deg pos.  The only difference I see is that the combined signal will be 180 deg different between the to positions of the receiving dipole.

Comment: It's simple vectors, you can create an E field inclined at 45 deg by equal vertical and horizontal components, and this is what happens when you drive them in phase. Here's a paper where crossed bow-ties are used to generate vertical, horiz, 45deg, LH and RH circular pol by simply changing the feed amplitudes/phasing: https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=8082750

Answer (score 0):

You've already specified that you have a line-of-sight environment, so you've told us that there is no scattering to cause inadvertent polarisation rotation due to reflection from inclined surfaces.

However, you've neglected the receive antenna. It is polarised. It's either linearly or circularly polarised.

If linear, then depending on its orientation it will receive only the x-pol, or the y-pol, or if inclined to both x and y it will pick both and add them together. This is a form of beam-forming, where the received signal is f(orientation) rather than f(bearing_from_transmitter), at least if the transmitter antennae are co-sited. If they are separated, then the reception is f(orientation, bearing_from_transmitter).

If circular, then the behaviour is more interesting. It will phase shift one by 90 degrees, then add both together.